# VB trouble loading data from a text file to list box

Tags: vb.net, list, text-files

I am trying to get my application to show data from a text file to a list box with visual basics. I have it working for small sized text files no problem, but it will not work for text files the size of say 20mb. Is there any reason why it wouldn't load such or maybe some kind of limitations?

I forgot to ask, could it possibly just a matter of having to wait a long time? The program just sits there and I can't interact with it while it's getting the data...I think anyway....

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim myName As String = Dir(downloadTo + "*.TXT")
    Do While myName <> ""
        lstFiles.Items.Add(myName)
        myName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub ReadFiles(textFile As String)

    Dim logReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textFile)

    lstSrchTxt.Items.Clear()
    While logReader.EndOfStream <> True

        Dim stringx As String = logReader.ReadLine

        If stringx.Contains(searchText) Then
            lstSrchTxt.Items.Add(stringx)
        End If
    End While

    logReader.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry if i dont give too much off the code away as this is for my company, so im limited to what i can show, but id say that should be enough. fyi, lstFiles and lstSrchTxt are from the design part of the code, like the gui, they are just lists that will display the data and receive data, etc

Comment: you can watch the progress of both of the subs with a  `Console.WriteLine(textfile & ": " & stringx)` after the `Dim stringx As String = logReader.ReadLine` line; that will at least let you know if the application is hanging, or just going slowly.

Comment: found out that it just takes a while for the program to run cause there is so much data, doubt ill be able to speed it up though, has to scan through 200000000> characters searching for specific words in each sentence, dont ask why i have to do this as its work related and i cant give away details about it :/ thanks for all the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was entering too much data and it needed time to process all of the characters.